# How to pad dates with 0's in a data file?

Tags: linux, awk, padding

I have a data file contain the following columns

```
Current Date     FirstName    LastName
 8/31/2014         AAA          BBB
 8/31/2014         CCC          DDD
```

What I want to do is extract the date in the CurrentDate column, convert it and put it into a new column with just the year and the month.

Like this:

```
CurrentMonth  CurrentDate     FirstName    LastName
 201408       8/31/2014         AAA          BBB
 201408       8/31/2014         CCC          DDD
```

I tried with  awk command

`awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} { { split($1, val,"/") } print val[3] val[1],$0}' > outputFile`

However the above command gives me 20148 rather than the 201408.

```
CurrentMonth  CurrentDate     FirstName    LastName
 20148       8/31/2014         AAA          BBB
 20148       8/31/2014         CCC          DDD
```

How do I pad 0's into the date?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `printf`:

```
awk -F $'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} { { split($1, val,"/") } printf "%04d%02d\t%s\n", val[3], val[1],$0}'
```

`printf` in awk works much the same as `printf` in C; you can find the specifications for the format language on any C reference site (e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)). Briefly, in a format specification like `%04d`, `%` introduces a format operator, `0` means pad with zeros, `4` means the width to print out, and `d` means "print as a decimal number".

This awk script yields

```
201408  8/31/2014   AAA BBB
201408  8/31/2014   CCC DDD
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you mind explain to me the meaning of "%04d%02d\t%s\n" ?

Comment: Can you explain the `$` in the Field Separator? I would have just used this: `awk 'code'` since tab is default field separator for input and you controls the output with `printf`.

Comment: @Jotne tab is not the default field separator, it's just one of the white space chars included in the default field separator. The OP didn't show any field with non-tab spaces in them but since (s)he's specifying tabs in the example, may as well stick with it. The `$` is used to generate a literal character in shell so in shell `$'\t'` is a literal tab char while `\t` is the escape sequence that represents a tab char. Either one would work just fine for awk.

Comment: `{ split($1, val,"/") }` should be `split($1, val,"/");`. The former would work, just doesn't really make sense syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

with `printf` function in awk, use `%02s`

Here is the code

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "CurrentMonth  CurrentDate     FirstName    LastName"} 
     NR>1{split($1,a,"/"); printf "%s%02s\t\t%s\n",a[3],a[1],$0}' infile

CurrentMonth  CurrentDate     FirstName    LastName
201408       8/31/2014         AAA          BBB
201408       8/31/2014         CCC          DDD
```

Comment: This is more or less a copy of `nneonneos` post, posted 15 min before you. (except the first line).

Comment: Was not to offend you.  I see often that one question is more or less the same as another, since idea is the same. :)